# How to get the result of mongoose aggregate function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am trying to get the result of group by in mongoose below given is my query

```
const sumByNetType= await mongoose.connection.db.collection(f)
.aggregate([{$match:{"network_type":n}},{$group: 
{_id:"$network_type",'total': { '$sum': { '$toInt': '$cost' } }}}])
```

the above query is giving me aggregate constructor back i guess below given is the output

```
  cursorState:
 { cursorId: null,
 cmd:
  { aggregate: 'dailylogs20190115', pipeline: [Array], cursor: {} },
 documents: [],
 cursorIndex: 0,
 dead: false,
 killed: false,
 init: false,
 notified: false,
 limit: 0,
 skip: 0,
 batchSize: 1000,
 currentLimit: 0,
 transforms: undefined,
 reconnect: true },
 logger: Logger { className: 'Cursor' },
_readableState:
 ReadableState {
 objectMode: true,
 highWaterMark: 16,
 buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
 length: 0,
 pipes: null,
 pipesCount: 0,
 flowing: null,
 ended: false,
 endEmitted: false,
 reading: false,
 sync: true,
 needReadable: false,
 emittedReadable: false,
 readableListening: false,
 resumeScheduled: false,
 emitClose: true,
 destroyed: false,
 defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
 awaitDrain: 0,
 readingMore: false,
 decoder: null,
 encoding: null },
 readable: true,
```

what should i do to get the result?

Comment: Hey, have you tried with defining Model or schema and use aggregate in that? without doing aggregate direct in toplevel

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty sir issue is i have numerous preexisting collections e.g daily0,daily1,daily2,.....dailyn so i am confused basically that should i make model or schema of each and every preexisting collection

Comment: hey , have added the answer, dont forget to upvote, if worked ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, so after researching on this. i saw the output you getting here is [AggregationCursor](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/AggregationCursor.html) .

we can easily get the docs from here using [`.toArray()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/) as you want.
or may be you can use cursor to iterate over if there is lots of docs.
and you can do many things using cursor. check out docs for [`cursor`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-cursor/) .

in your case you can just add [`.toArray()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/) :

```
const sumByNetType= await mongoose.connection.db.collection(f)
.aggregate([{$match:{"network_type":n}},{$group: 
{_id:"$network_type",'total': { '$sum': { '$toInt': '$cost' } }}}]).toArray();
```

if you want to iterate over your all docs of that query, 
you can do something like this may be:

```
const cursor= await mongoose.connection.db.collection(f)
.aggregate([{$match:{"network_type":n}},{$group: 
{_id:"$network_type",'total': { '$sum': { '$toInt': '$cost' } }}}]);

//this will just iterate over the results
 cursor.each(function(err, docs) {
       console.log(docs)
  // do something using the doc,
        if(docs == null) {
            mongoose.connection.db.close(); //close the connection
      }
  });
```